# Is my macbook pro dying?

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, memory, gpu

I have a Macbook pro 4,1 early 2008.

It's a great machine for surfing while the TV is on, but it's starting to act strange.

[image: Sameple shot 1]

[image]

These screenshots are both of a google sheet -- same one a few minutes apart.

I can see two possibilities:

A:  My GPU is dying, and doesn't work in certain modes.

B:  I've got a bad memory stick.

How do I diagnose which?

Comment: Are these pictures or screenshots? If they're pictures, next time you encounter the problem, try taking a screenshot.

Comment: They are screenshots.  Why?

Comment: Because a bad display would capture a clean picture whereas a bad GPU would capture the distorted picture.   Your GPU is probably toast.

Answer (score 4):

Run Apple Apple Hardware Test.

Apple Hardware Test (AHT) contains a suite of diagnostics that test the hardware of your Mac.

Here is the official support article by Apple:
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201257

And the relevant instructions, "Turn on your Mac, then immediately press and hold the D key on your keyboard. Keep holding the D key until you see the Apple Hardware Test icon."

Comment: The problem with the hardware test is that the problem vanishes -- for a while -- on reboot.

Comment: Can you elaborate? Because hardware test won't just test for hardware problems that happen at reboot, but test the hardware in general against some checks and give you a report. Did you try the hardware test though? Did test report anything?